# WebService with JAXB - arguments contains null

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, jaxb

I am trying to write simple web service to test something. I have the following simple request XSD:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://processonlinejob.ws/processOnlineJobRequest" targetNamespace="http://processonlinejob.ws/processOnlineJobRequest" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <element name="processOnlineJobRequest">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="template">
                    <complexType>
                        <sequence>
                            <element name="name" type="string"/>
                            <element name="version" type="string"/>
                        </sequence>
                    </complexType>
                </element>
                <element name="data" type="tns:processOnlineJobData"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
    <complexType name="processOnlineJobData">
        <sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <any processContents="skip"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

And the following simple response XSD:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://processonlinejob.ws/processOnlineJobResponse" targetNamespace="http://processonlinejob.ws/processOnlineJobResponse" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <element name="processOnlineJobResponse" type="tns:processOnlineJobResponse"/>
    <complexType name="processOnlineJobResponse">
        <sequence>
            <element name="resultCode" type="short" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <element name="resultMessage" type="string" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <element name="pdfBase64" type="base64Binary" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

I auto-generated JAXB classes via Eclipse (Spring tool suite 3.6.3 SR1) and written the following simple code:

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface ProcessOnlineJob {
    @WebMethod
    ProcessOnlineJobResponse processOnlineJob(ProcessOnlineJobRequest request);
}

@WebService(endpointInterface = "poc.ondemmand.ProcessOnlineJob")
public class ProcessOnlineJobImpl implements ProcessOnlineJob {
    @Override
    public ProcessOnlineJobResponse processOnlineJob(
            ProcessOnlineJobRequest request) {
        ProcessOnlineJobResponse response = new ProcessOnlineJobResponse();
        response.setResultCode((short) 1);
        response.setResultMessage("OK");
        byte[] data = { 1 };
        response.setPdfBase64(data);
        return response;
    }
}

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9999/ws/processonlinejob",
                    new ProcessOnlineJobImpl());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When run, I obtain the following strange error about null pointer parameter. What is wrong ? I have tried to debug, but it goes directly to some internall sun jaxb library classes :-(.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument contains null
    at com.sun.xml.internal.txw2.Document.writeValue(Document.java:130)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.txw2.Document.writeValue(Document.java:134)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.txw2.StartTag.addAttribute(StartTag.java:120)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.txw2.ContainerElement._attribute(ContainerElement.java:303)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.txw2.ContainerElement.addAttribute(ContainerElement.java:160)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.txw2.ContainerElement.invoke(ContainerElement.java:134)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.type(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.writer.WSDLGenerator.generateSOAPMessages(WSDLGenerator.java:573)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.writer.WSDLGenerator.generateMessages(WSDLGenerator.java:545)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.writer.WSDLGenerator.generateDocument(WSDLGenerator.java:436)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.writer.WSDLGenerator.doGeneration(WSDLGenerator.java:321)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.generateWSDL(DatabindingImpl.java:242)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.EndpointFactory.generateWSDL(EndpointFactory.java:622)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:277)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:144)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:563)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:545)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.createEndpoint(EndpointImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:231)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(ProviderImpl.java:126)
    at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Endpoint.java:240)
    at poc.ondemmand.Program.main(Program.java:22)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I have found that when I change XSD to the following, everything works. It seems to me, that JAXB demmands public types in XSD. So workaround is to use :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://processonlinejob.ws/processOnlineJobRequest" targetNamespace="http://processonlinejob.ws/processOnlineJobRequest" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <element name="processOnlineJobRequest" type="tns:processOnlineJobRequest"/>
    <complexType name="processOnlineJobData">
        <sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <any processContents="skip"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="templateType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="name" type="string"/>
            <element name="version" type="string"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="processOnlineJobRequest">
        <sequence>
            <element name="template" type="tns:templateType"/>
            <element name="data" type="tns:processOnlineJobData"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling on this error today still, I had the same issue and found that it was caused by a class in the response type of the endpoint that implemented the **Clonable** interface. Removing that solves the problem. Be sure that when you remove it that you do not break other functionality though.